# Map a Json string to pojo class inside entity class - Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson

I am trying to map a JSON String object from my DB to a transient member inside the entity class.
But when I am getting the response it's coming as null.

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong ?

```
  @Entity
    @Getters
    //other annotations
    public class Person {
    
    // members
    
    @Lob
    @JsonIgnore
    String personData;

@Transient
@JsonIclude
PersonData personDataDetails

public PersonData getPersonDataDetails(){

    //Create Object Mapper obj
     return objectMapper.readValue(personData, PersonData.class);

 }

}
```

but in the output personDataDetails is coming as null. How I can assign the value to personDataDetails and get the same in the response ?

Comment: What's your JSON String?

Comment: I believe this is the nature of Transient isn't it ? Variables marked as transient aren't `Serialized` ! So ultimately will be skipped in JSON to POJO and Vice-versa conversion to my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

If you have Serialization problem, Make sure that you add both Getters and Setters to your PersonData class to all needed params

```
public class PersonData {

String name;
Integer age;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

if you think problem caused by annotations you have used, Your output will not have null, but dont have personDataDetails param at all